# Smooth scrolling with recycler view android

Tags: android

I have recycler view with different type of cards inside it with lots of images and nested recycler view for every card. While scrolling recycler view I am getting lot of jerk can someone help me on this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: How are you getting the images? If they are from a URL, you should get them in an Async task

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I am getting images from a URL and I am using https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader for loading them